# Need help identify a piece

Tags: piece-information

It's some kind of tile with a bench shape.

[image]

Comment: Which set are you building?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [this](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4865b#T=C), [this](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=23950#T=C), or [this](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30413#T=C)

Personally, I would say it's the 3L version in dark gray but it's hard to tell without a better picture of the parts on the page around it.

Hope that helped.